# Sending an animated Gif via sms in Swift

Tags: swift, gif, animated-gif, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to send an animated gif via the MFMessageComposeViewController in swift,

It seems to be working fine when I send the gif, however the preview shows a non-moving image. Any thoughts on how to make the preview animated?

```
let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()      
let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://dramallamaapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/output_9GECbQ.gif")!)
if imgData != nil {
    messageComposeVC.addAttachmentData(imgData!, typeIdentifier: "com.compuserve.gif", filename: "animated.gif")
}
messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I now believe this is default iOS behavior, as with iMessages the same happens (gif shows as an image until sent, then begins animating).